Unknown error in API end point in django restframework
I am using django rest framework to create an API and I have the following models that relate to each other
#A custom user model
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    DEPARTMENT_CLASSIFICATION = [
        ('operations', 'operations'),
        ('engineering', 'engineering'),
        ('safety', 'safety'),
        ('analytics', 'analytics'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=0)  # Assuming a maximum length for mobile number
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DEPARTMENT_CLASSIFICATION)
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile_number']  # Add 'mobile_number' to REQUIRED_FIELDS

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

# A drone model 
class Drones(models.Model):
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    UAS = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    insuarance_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    flight_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.serial_no})"

# A battery log model 
class BatteryLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drone = models.ForeignKey(Drones, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    B_serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    takeoff_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    landing_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tcycle = models.TimeField()
    BMake = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    BCapacity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Btype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inspection_date = models.DateField()
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'BatteryLog - {self.B_serial_no}'
# A flight record model
class FlightRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    drone = models.ForeignKey(Drones, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="drone")
    battery_log = models.ForeignKey(BatteryLog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="battery")
    takeoff_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
    landing_percentage = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
    tcycle = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    inspect_date = models.DateField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    starttime = models.TimeField()
    endtime = models.TimeField()
    flight_hours = models.IntegerField()  # Actual flight hours entered by the user
    #running_total = models.IntegerField()  # Actual running hours entered by the user
    cumulative_flight_hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # Cumulative flight hours calculated over multiple entries
    #cumulative_running_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # Cumulative running total calculated over multiple entries
    pilot_commands = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    corrective_action = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Drone - {self.drone}'

I have this view that authenticates the user and generates a token and retrieves users details
jwt_secret_key = settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY
#Log the user in and authenticate a user and produce a token
class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if not user or not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Incorrect email or password")
        
        payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': timezone.now()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, jwt_secret_key, algorithm="HS256")
        print("Token before encoding:", token)
        print("payload", payload)
        print("secret key", jwt_secret_key)
        
        response = Response()
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        response.data = {'jwt': token}
        return response
#Retrives user details
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Unauthenticated")

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, jwt_secret_key, algorithms=['HS256'])
            print("Decoded payload:", payload)
            print("secret key", jwt_secret_key)
            print("Token before encoding:", token)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Token has expired")
        except jwt.InvalidSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Invalid token signature")
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Invalid token")

        user_id = payload.get('id')
        if not user_id:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Invalid token")

        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=user_id).first()
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("User not found")

        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)


Here is my settings.py file with authentication settings and secret key settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "ecowings.CustomUser"


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
        
    ),
}
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

JWT_SECRET_KEY = '106931045983'


I am trying to post data in the FlightRecord model using the following serializer in which it is supposed to be associated with the user(specifically the user's name who posted the FlightRecord) the drone(specifically the drone's name) and the Battery(specifically the battery serial number) and calculate the total cumulative _hours and associate it with user and drone object
#Handle FlightRecord
class TechLogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = FlightRecord
        # Exclude the 'user' field from the serializer, as it will be automatically set in the view
        exclude = ['user']

Here is the view that handles the posting of the data in serializer
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics
from ecowings.models.logsheet import FlightRecord
from ecowings.models.models import Drones, BatteryLog
from ecowings.serializers import TechLogsSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class AddFlightRecordView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TechLogsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    serializer_class = TechLogsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return FlightRecord.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.copy()
        
        drone_id = data.pop('drone_id', None)
        battery_log_id = data.pop('battery_log_id', None)
        
     
        drone = get_object_or_404(Drones, pk=drone_id)
        battery_log = get_object_or_404(BatteryLog, pk=battery_log_id)
        
        data['user'] = request.user.id
        data['drone'] = drone.id
        data['battery_log'] = battery_log.id
        
        serializer = TechLogsSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            cumulative_flight_hours = data['flight_hours'] + drone.cumulative_flight_hours
            if cumulative_flight_hours > 100:
                return Response({'error': 'The selected drone has exceeded the maximum cumulative flight hours of 100 hours.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            
            serializer.save()
            user_flight_records = FlightRecord.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            cumulative_flight_hours = sum(record.flight_hours for record in user_flight_records)
            user_flight_records.update(cumulative_flight_hours=cumulative_flight_hours)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

I am trying to post the following data in the FlightRecord model using this request in postman
{
    "drone": 1,
    "battery_log": 1,
    "takeoff_percentage": "50%",
    "landing_percentage": "50%",
    "tcycle": 1,
    "date": "2024-05-13",
    "inspect_date": "2024-05-13",
    "location": "Test Location",
    "starttime": "10:00:00",
    "endtime": "11:00:00",
    "flight_hours": 1,
    "cumulative_flight_hours": 1,
    "pilot_commands": "Test Pilot",
    "corrective_action": "Test Action"
}


I keep getting this error
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}

All of this error despite getting the correct token printed below inputted in the headers
Decoded payload: {'id': 1, 'exp': 1715638281, 'iat': 1715634681}
secret key 106931045983
Token before encoding: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNzE1NjM4MjgxLCJpYXQiOjE3MTU2MzQ2ODF9.YvDP_3QnvYQD0VcdBQHkvxddsBBVCnYaWkJp6W54CU8
[14/May/2024 00:12:41] "GET /api/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 138


How are you setting the JWT for your request in Postman?
